# python how to get instance variables of a class to another class?

Tags: python, class, oop, variables

I have two classes. When I create an instance in the first one would like to work with its attributes in my second class.

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number_of_tricks = number

class Statistics(object):
    def get_number_of_tricks(self):
        return Dog(Max.number_of_tricks)
```

Now I create a instance `>>> Max = Dog(15)` and want the class "Statistics" be able to gain its value "number_of_tricks". For example something like `>>> stat = Statistics()`, `>>>stat.get_number_of_tricks()`

Comment: Why did you change `self` to `snelf` in `get_number_of_tricks`?

Comment: a typing error, thanks for the notification

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize your `Statistics` with that instance of `Dog`, then the attributes of that `Dog` will be accessible from `Statistics`:

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number_of_tricks = number

class Statistics(object):
    def __init__(self, dog_instance):
        self.dog = dog_instance

    def get_number_of_tricks(self):
        return self.dog.number_of_tricks
```

And you can do:

```
>>> from my_module import Dog, Statistics
>>> Max = Dog(15)
>>> stat = Statistics(Max)
>>> stat.get_number_of_tricks()
15
```